# Assign negative of unsigned to a signed, is it OK?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, unsigned

When I run this:

```
int main() {
    unsigned a = 5;
    std::cout << -a << std::endl;
    int b = -a; 
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

```
4294967291
-5
```

**It seems like it works, and I can take the negative of an `unsigned` and assign it to an `int`, but is this really always OK? Why?**

When I try something that to me looks like a similar situation:

```
int c = 1;
int d = 3;
double x = c/d;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

I get `0` (as expected).

PS: Maybe there is a dupe and I didnt find it, closest I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253097/what-happens-with-the-negative-of-an-unsigned-integer)

Comment: I am "almost" sure C++ inherits this type conversion from C - consider to add C tag and search C area.. E.g. read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605/signed-to-unsigned-conversion-in-c-is-it-always-safe.

Comment: It is just a binary magic. The same binary representation is interpreted as a signed or unsigned value differently.

Comment: see also here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221409/is-unsigned-integer-subtraction-defined-behavior

Comment: @JonnyHenly with "always OK" I meant that I wasnt sure if I just hit a lucky example, because actually I didnt expect this to work. The second example is because the only way I could explain the behaviour is that the rhs is somehow promoted to signed (ie. the type on the lhs) before the assignment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**. You have *undefined behaviour* possibilities.

Here is a counter-example that produces UB when assigning a negated `unsigned int` to an `int`:

```
unsigned u = (unsigned)std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - 1;
std::cout << "max int" << std::numeric_limits<int>::max() << '\n';
std::cout << "as unsigned - 1" << u << '\n';
std::cout << "negated:" << -u << '\n';
std::cout << std::boolalpha << ( std::numeric_limits<int>::max() < -u ) << '\n';
int s = -u;
std::cout << s << '\n';
```

On my machine:
`int`'s max value is 2'147'483'647, but the negated `unsigned int` has a value of 2'147'483'650; that value is greater than the max value that can be represented by an `int`. Know that signed overflow is undefined behaviour. Thus, the algorithm is not safe for all of its possible values.

The Standard's (2016-07-12: N4604) word:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically deﬁned or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is undeﬁned. [ Note: Treatment of division by
>   zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all ﬂoating point
>   exceptions vary among machines, and is sometimes adjustable by a
>   library function. — end note ]

---

In the future, you can use the `{}`-style initialization to prevent such issues:

```
unsigned a = 5;
std::cout << -a << '\n';
int b{ -a }; // compiler detects narrowing conversions, warning/error
std::cout << b << '\n';
return 0;
```

Note that even though you know that `-a` will be a value that can be represented by an `int`, your compiler still warns you.

On signed overflow:

[Is signed integer overflow still undefined behavior in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16188263/2296177)

On well defined unsigned overflow in both C and C++:

[Why is unsigned integer overflow defined behavior but signed integer overflow isn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195715/2296177)

On implicit conversions:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Comment: @cmaster If you assign a value that is larger than what can be represented by the `int`, you trigger UB. Even if the original operation on the `unsigned` is well defined.

Comment: @cmaster I have not seen that.  C++14 still has [expr]/4 *If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: @cmaster I've added a quote from a recent C++ standard that contradicts what you say. Remember that this question is C++, and you might be correct in C.

Comment: Ok, probably you are right for C++. Deleted my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It is OK just as long as your target architecture is using two's compliment arithmetic and is treating `int` as 32 bits. Otherwise you'll get different results for your first program.